# How to compile all of proto file which in the specify path?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am new to protocol Buffers. I have read the documentation and get a command to compile proto, but it only worked to compile single proto file.

```bash
protoc --proto_path=$ABSOLUTE_PATH --java_out=$OUT_SRC $MY_FILE.proto
```

After that, I tried to use wildcard to match all of proto files in the specified file path, but I get an error which is:

> Could not make proto path relative: .proto: No such file or directory

Below is my env config

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.12.4

$ uname -v
#64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023
```

I have tried the wildcard ,it is invalid.

```bash
protoc --proto_path=$ABSOLUTE_PATH --java_out=$OUT_SRC *.proto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protoc` is **very** particular about paths.

When you specify `proto_path`'s, you **must** then specify one of the `proto_path`'s for every `*.proto` reference.

So, in your case:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${ABSOLUTE_PATH} \
--java_out=$OUT_SRC \
${ABSOLUTE_PATH}/*.proto
```

Because you specified one `proto_path`, every subsequent `*.proto` reference must be explicitly reference against that path.

As a working model, I always use `--proto_path=${PWD}` even if I only have a single proto (e.g. `foo.proto`) in the working folder:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--xxx_out=... \
${PWD}/foo.proto
```